# App Interruption - Siri Fails To Hear Human Voice

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, siri

In my team's iOS app we have a bug when Siri is invoked while our app is running. Siri pops up and the waveform is shown very briefly and appears not to detect one's voice as the waveform remains very flat. Quickly thereafter it begins to list the things you can ask Siri.

We are using Xcode 6.3, tested on an iPad Mini with iOS 8.3 as well as an iPhone 5 with iOS 8.3.

The app never uses the microphone or queries any of the device audio inputs so I can't see this problem attributed to our app using the microphone directly. It does play looping ambient music and has sound effects.

Is there anything specific we should be calling an an interruption to ensure that Siri will work properly? Has anyone experienced similar issues?

Comment: Not sure, but I've encountered other apps that do this.  Good on you for working to prevent it.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely not related to your app. The iOS SDK doesn't provide a Siri API that could lead to this kind of events.

You may try to pause any ambient music/sounds effects whenever the app goes in background. (in AppDelegate.m)